# How to Ensure Modal Close Animation Plays on ESC Key Press in React with Framer Motion?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, framer-motion

I'm using Framer Motion with React to animate a modal component's entrance and exit. The modal currently closes as expected when clicking outside of it or using a close button, with the exit animations playing smoothly. However, when I press the ESC key, although the modal closes, the exit animation does not play.

The modal automatically closes on the ESC key press by default (I'm assuming this is default browser behavior or provided by a library), but it skips the exit animation defined in Framer Motion's AnimatePresence.

here is simplified code.
// ModalWrapper.jsx

```
<AnimatePresence mode="wait">
  {isOpen && (
    <Modal ref={dialogRef} open={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
      {children}
    </Modal>
  )}
</AnimatePresence>
```

// Modal.jsx

```
<motion.dialog
  key="modal"
  ref={ref}
  className={classes.modal}
  onClose={onClose}
  onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
  variants={dropIn}
  initial="hidden"
  animate="visible"
  exit="exit">
  {children}
</motion.dialog>
```

thank you!

I am expecting to play exit animation on esc key.